# Image url on firebase database not showing correct http Url ""com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@1234567""

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading images to the Firebase database and storage. 
In the storage i can see the HTTP Url, however in my firebase database it is not retrieving the HTTP Url with the image.

However Instead it retrieves the following 
Image "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@d678887"

Ive tried to look at the firebase codes and use addOnlisterners but no change. Struggling to understand where ive gone wrong

```
public class PostActivity extends Fragment implements SelectPhotoDialog.OnPhotoSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "PostFragment";

    @Override
    public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getImagePath: setting the image to imageview");


        UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imagePath.toString(), mPostImage);
        //assign to global variable
        mSelectedBitmap = null;
        mSelectedUri = imagePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void getImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getImageBitmap: setting the image to imageview");
        mPostImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //assign to a global variable
        mSelectedUri = null;
        mSelectedBitmap = bitmap;
    }

    //widgets
    private ImageView mPostImage;
    private EditText mTitle, mDescription, mPrice, mCountry, mStateProvince, mCity, mContactEmail;
    private Button mPost;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    //vars
    private Bitmap mSelectedBitmap;
    private Uri mSelectedUri;
    private byte[] mUploadBytes;
    private double mProgress = 0;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_post, container, false);
        mPostImage = view.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        mTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.input_title);
        mDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.input_description);
        mPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.input_price);
        mCountry = view.findViewById(R.id.input_country);
        mStateProvince = view.findViewById(R.id.input_state_province);
        mCity = view.findViewById(R.id.input_city);
        mContactEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        mPost = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_post);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));




        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        init();

        return view;
    }

    private void init(){

        mPostImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening dialog to choose new photo");
                SelectPhotoDialog dialog = new SelectPhotoDialog();
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.dialog_select_photo));
                dialog.setTargetFragment(PostActivity.this, 1);
            }
        });

        mPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to post...");
                if(!isEmpty(mTitle.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mDescription.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mPrice.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mCountry.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mStateProvince.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mCity.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mContactEmail.getText().toString())){

                    //we have a bitmap and no Uri
                    if(mSelectedBitmap != null && mSelectedUri == null){
                        uploadNewPhoto(mSelectedBitmap);
                    }
                    //we have no bitmap and a uri
                    else if(mSelectedBitmap == null && mSelectedUri != null){
                        uploadNewPhoto(mSelectedUri);
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You must fill out all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void uploadNewPhoto(Bitmap bitmap){
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: uploading a new image bitmap to storage");
        BackgroundImageResize resize = new BackgroundImageResize(bitmap);
        Uri uri = null;
        resize.execute(uri);
    }

    private void uploadNewPhoto(Uri imagePath){
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: uploading a new image uri to storage.");
        BackgroundImageResize resize = new BackgroundImageResize(null);
        resize.execute(imagePath);
    }

    public class BackgroundImageResize extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, byte[]>{

        Bitmap mBitmap;

        public BackgroundImageResize(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(bitmap != null){
                this.mBitmap = bitmap;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "compressing image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showProgressBar();
        }

        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Uri... params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: started.");

            if(mBitmap == null){
                try{
                    RotateBitmap rotateBitmap = new RotateBitmap();
                    mBitmap = rotateBitmap.HandleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(getActivity(), params[0]);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            byte[] bytes = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + mBitmap.getByteCount() / 1000000 );
            bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + bytes.length / 1000000 );
            return bytes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
            super.onPostExecute(bytes);
            mUploadBytes = bytes;
            hideProgressBar();
            //execute the upload task
            executeUploadTask();
        }
    }

    private void executeUploadTask(){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final String postId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();

        final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                        "/" + postId + "/post_image");

        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(mUploadBytes);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            //insert the download url into the firebase database
            //Uri firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            Task<Uri> firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    System.out.println(uri.toString());



                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //Handle any errors
                }
            });

            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: firebase download url: " + firebaseUri.toString());
                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    Post post = new Post();
                    post.setImage(downloadUrl.toString());
                    post.setCity(mCity.getText().toString());
                    post.setContact_email(mContactEmail.getText().toString());
                    post.setCountry(mCountry.getText().toString());
                    post.setDescription(mDescription.getText().toString());
                    post.setPost_id(postId);
                    post.setPrice(mPrice.getText().toString());
                    post.setState_province(mStateProvince.getText().toString());
                    post.setTitle(mTitle.getText().toString());
                    post.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                    reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                            .child(postId)
                            .setValue(post);

                    resetFields();
                }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "could not upload photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double currentProgress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                if( currentProgress > (mProgress + 15)){
                    mProgress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgress: upload is " + mProgress + "& done");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mProgress + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality,stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }


    private void resetFields(){
        UniversalImageLoader.setImage("", mPostImage);
        mTitle.setText("");
        mDescription.setText("");
        mPrice.setText("");
        mCountry.setText("");
        mStateProvince.setText("");
        mCity.setText("");
        mContactEmail.setText("");
    }

    private void showProgressBar(){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    private void hideProgressBar(){
        if(mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return true if the @param is null
     * @param string
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isEmpty(String string){
        return string.equals("");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above log won't work cause it provides you Task which is `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@1234567` try putting log inside the onSuccess.

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //insert the download url into the firebase database
            //Uri firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: firebase download url: " + firebaseUri.toString());
                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    Post post = new Post();
                    post.setImage(downloadUrl.toString());
                    post.setCity(mCity.getText().toString());
                    post.setContact_email(mContactEmail.getText().toString());
                    post.setCountry(mCountry.getText().toString());
                    post.setDescription(mDescription.getText().toString());
                    post.setPost_id(postId);
                    post.setPrice(mPrice.getText().toString());
                    post.setState_province(mStateProvince.getText().toString());
                    post.setTitle(mTitle.getText().toString());
                    post.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                    reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                            .child(postId)
                            .setValue(post);

                    resetFields();
                }
            })
```

and start storing inside the onSuccess so you can get the uri in database.

Comment: is the filepath my storage ref or database ref ? filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()

Comment: storage reference.

Comment: i tried putting log inside the onSuccess but i get errors on my Post () after the log

Comment: it's probably null pointer exception because your getdownload url in async call

Comment: i added the storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() { ...
}

however i get errors for my other code and resetFields() cannot be resolved

Comment: Please join room so i can help you there properly https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200008/help-room.